# How to set mysql password automatically in bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a bash script that opens queries from MySQL.
For example:

```
$ cat script.sh 
mysql -u joe -D database -p ........ < first_query.sql
mysql -u joe -D database -p ........ < second_query.sql
```

This 2 lines inside my script.sh file return the results of the queries, but: Everytime I call the ‘mysql’ command, if it has the «-p» option, it asks for password TWICE (because I call mysql twice). How can I avoid this behavior?

I have tried passing my password as parameter, for example:

```
$ sh script.sh ‘mypassword’
```

and storing it in a variable and putting it after the «-p» option.
But it still asks for the password twice.

Comment: You have two valid answers. You should pick your favorite and mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your password staight after the -p. If you password is "123asd", the command will be:

```
mysql -u user -p123asd
```

Make sure there are no spaces between -p and your password.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way would be to edit your `my.cnf` (found in */etc/mysql/* by default) to include your password, like so:

```
[client]
user = joe
password = ......
```